# How to index into Array of Dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift

I have an object that looks like this in the console. It seems like an array with a dictionary inside.  How can I get to the address field?

```
Optional((
        {
        address = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
        verified = 1;
    }
))
```

The object comes from this object:

```
<METDocument key: <collection: users, ID: KTsCySacEAiz3eDnf>, fields: {
    emails =     (
                {
            address = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
            verified = 1;
        }
    );
    profile =     {
        address =         {
            city = Oslo;
            country = nor;
            lineOne = "address";
            lineTwo = "";
            zip = 0264;
        };
        birthdate = "1985-09-01 23:00:00 +0000";
        card =         {
            last4 = 4242;
            verified = 1;
        };
        filledOut = 1;
        gender = Male;
        name =         {
            first = "Elon";
            last = "Musk";
        };
        phone = 911;
        validated = 1;
    };
}>
```

I access the emails key by this method:

```
let emails = users.allDocuments[0].valueForKey("emails")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the object is an optional array.

There are two options:

- Safe access:

  ```
  if let emails = users.allDocuments[0].objectForKey("emails") where emails.count > 0 {
    if let address = emails[0]["address"] as? String {
      print(address)
    }
  }
  ```
- If it's guaranteed that the dictionary in the array and the key `address` exists:

  ```
  let emails = users.allDocuments[0].objectForKey("emails")!
  let address = emails[0]["address"] as! String
  ```

Comment: This works great, why does this not work?:  let userProfileEmail   =   userDocument.valueForKey("emails")![0]  I get error:Ambiguous use of 'subscript'

Comment: First off all, don't use `valueForKey`, that's a key value coding method with a special meaning. Regarding your question: Because the compiler can not definitely infer the type of `emails` when the whole expression is written in one line.

Comment: Swift is extremely type dependent/reliant/sensitive, is that a correct assessment?

Comment: Yes, type safety is one of the essential characteristics of Swift